# Writing in a Text File

Tags: c, file, printf, text-files

So, I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE *ReadFile, *WriteFile;
        float key;
        int quantKeys,T;

        int i;

        /* errors verification */

        if (argc < 3){
            printf(" Use the correct entry parameters.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((ReadFile = fopen(argv[1],"rw")) == NULL){
            printf("Error when trying to open the file\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if((WriteFile = fopen(argv[2],"rw")) == NULL){
            printf("Error when trying to open the file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* main code */

        quantKeys = 45658;
        T = 5;

        fprintf(WriteFile,"%d",T);
        fprintf(WriteFile,"%d",quantKeys);
        fclose(ReadFile);
        fclose(WriteFile);

    return 0;
    }
```

All I want to do is write the variables "quantChaves" and "T" in a text file, that I pass as the third parameter of the main function. It compiles and runs with no problems, but my text file keeps empty after I run it.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `#include <malloc.h>`  is obsolete. Use `#include <stdlib.h>`. And please, have your identifiers and messages in English. Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux)

Comment: You can also ask the question on pt.stackoverflow.com if you prefer to keep thing in portuguese.

Comment: Put it in english, thanks!

Comment: You may want to add a space or hard return after writing your first `"%d"`. As it is, the two numbers will appear right after each other, with no separator.

Answer (score 6):

`rw` isn't a valid mode for `fopen`. If you want to write, you can use `w`, `w+`, `r+`, or `a+`. Full details are in your `man` pages, or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

The gist of the differences:

`w` doesn't allow reading

`r+` doesn't create a new file if it doesn't exist

`a+` appends the text instead of overwriting the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write in a file you should use

- `w`  : Create an empty file
- `w+` : Create an empty file and open it for update
- `r+` : Open a file for update
- `a+` : Open a file for update with all output operations writing data at the end of the file
  **not** rw.
  You can read more about [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csto/fopen/di).